# htaccess rewrite rule for account nickname

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have htaccess rewrite rule that allows account nickname to be like **domain.com/its_super-nick.name3000**

Here is the regular expression I use, but it gives me an Internal Error back

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ index.php?cl=account&username=$1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "an Internal Error" - do you mean a "500 Internal Server error"? By itself, that shouldn't result in a 500 error (although it is still incorrect and will fail to work as intended). The 500 error may result in combination with other directives.

Comment: Please share the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ index.php?cl=account&username=$1
> ```

The "problem" here is that the regex also matches `index.php` (the rewritten URL). So, `username=index.php` will result from a second pass through the rewrite engine. (By itself, this shouldn't cause an "Internal Error" - if by that you mean a "500 Internal Server Error" - but in combination with other directives this could result in a rewrite loop, ie. a 500 Error)

And you are missing the `L` (`last`) flag.

The placement of the hyphen towards the end of the character class (as mentioned in the other answer) isn't actually an issue in this case (it will match a literal hyphen), however, you should move it to the start or end of the character class to avoid any ambiguity (and improve readability).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php$)([\w.-]+)/?$ index.php?cl=account&username=$1 [L]
```

This uses a negative lookahead to avoid matching `index.php`.

The shorthand character class `\w` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because of `9-_` as you probably wanted to match "A" to "Z", "a" to "z", "0" to "9" and then the chars "-", "_" and ".".

In this case you have to put the hyphen at the end:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_.-]+)/?$ index.php?cl=account&username=$1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work either

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't test it and I didn't think about the rewrite loop due to the regex matching the resulting URL. Using a negative lookahead in the rewrite rule or adding a rewrite condition could solve this loop issue.